# Disabling Behave Pro task on build server

Tags: jira, bamboo

I am using Behave Pro to pull acceptance criteria from JIRA in my Visual Studio solution.  This task runs on build and whilst this works fine locally when my build server builds the solution it fails to connect to JIRA.  This is because JIRA is on a different domain and inaccessible from the build server.

I can edit the Behave task when I unload my solution which looks like the example below.  Is there a way I can add some logic to stop this running on my build server (in this case Bamboo) as we can pull down acceptance criteria locally.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  Just but a condition to only call JIRA via Behave Pro on the Debug plan configuration.  On build server I use release.